# Image similarity measure

Tags: python, performance, image, edit-distance, genetic-algorithm

I'm attempting to speed up my genetic algorithm that modifies images. After searching, I've found that my `fitness` function is the bottleneck, taking sometimes up to 11 seconds to complete.

The `fitness` function accepts two images and returns a float representing the total difference between the images' corresponding pixels, measured as distance in Cartesian RGB space.

To test, I used some large images of the same size (1254 x 834). What can I do to speed this process up?

```
def fitness(original, new):
    fitness = 0

    for x in range(0, width):
        for y in range(0, height):
            r1, g1, b1 = original.getpixel((x, y))
            r2, g2, b2 = new.getpixel((x, y))

            deltaRed = abs(r1 - r2)
            deltaGreen = abs(g1 - g2)
            deltaBlue = abs(b1 - b2)

            pixelFitness = pixelFitness = math.sqrt(deltaRed ** 2 + deltaGreen ** 2 + deltaBlue ** 2)

            fitness += pixelFitness

    return fitness
```

Comment: getpixel((x, y)) is very likely to be the trouble, as it is very slow operation for every language(and API) I know. I dont know much of python but finding alternative should be easy task for you.

Comment: The three calls to `abs()` are pretty pointless, given that the only thing we do with the results is to square them.

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @wondra for the help. I rewrote the function without the `getpixel` and just loaded the pixels using the `image.load()` method. This caused the execution time to reduce down to 3.09 seconds.

Rewritten function:

```
def fitness_new(new):
    fitness = 0

    new_data = new.load()

    for x in range(0, width):
        for y in range(0, height):
            r1, g1, b1 = optimal_data[x, y]
            r2, g2, b2 = new_data[x, y]

            deltaRed = abs(r1 - r2)
            deltaGreen = abs(g1 - g2)
            deltaBlue = abs(b1 - b2)

            pixelFitness = pixelFitness = math.sqrt(deltaRed ** 2 + deltaGreen ** 2 + deltaBlue ** 2)

            fitness += pixelFitness

    return fitness
```

`optimal_data` is preloaded as a global variable instead of being passed as an argument, because it is accessed elsewhere. I know this is probably not the most ideal method.

Answer (score 2):

To speed this up further, you should use the [`numpy` interface of `PIL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44606972/4042267) (if you are not yet using `PIL`, you should, for this reason):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# `int` important because otherwise it might wrap around when subtracting
optimal_data = np.asarray(Image.open("optimal.png"), dtype=int) 
new = np.random.randint(0, 256, optimal_data.shape)

def fitness(optimal_data, new):
    return np.sqrt(((optimal_data - new)**2).sum(axis=-1)).sum()
```

This takes only 258 ms ± 2.21 ms for a 2424 x 2424 pixel image on my machine, while the [function by @TimCPogue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/79028/98493) takes 9.93 s ± 465 ms with the same images.

Note that the array has the shape `(width, height, channels)`, where `channels` is usually `4` (red, green, blue, alpha), not `3` like your code assumes. If you want to disregard differences in alpha, either set the alpha channel of the new image to the one of the optimal data (`new[:,:,-1] = optimal_data[:,:,-1]`), or slice in the fitness (`optimal_data[...,:-1] - new[...,:-1]`).

For some more readability and the possibility to use a different norm in the future (albeit at the cost of about 30% speed), you could make the norm to use a parameter and use [`np.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), as [suggested in the comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79023/improving-genetic-algorithm-fitness-function/209075#comment403968_209075) by [@GarethReese](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/11728/gareth-rees):

```
def fitness(optimal_data, new, norm=np.linalg.norm):
    return norm(optimal_data - new, axis=-1).sum()
```

Comment: Consider using [`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) instead of writing your own 2-norm.

Comment: @GarethRees: While it does make it more readable, it is about 30% slower. Even after making `norm = np.linalg.norm` a local variable.